# Is it possible to set primary key NOT as AUTOINCREMENT with Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

`HasKey()` method creates **autoincrement** PK when applied to `int` properties. I need an `int` PK but with **no** autoincrement on it.

Comment: Why do you need a PK then, can you clarify in better details of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @zaggler, basically, I need to identify my records by their int ID, but the records themselves come from another data source with IDs already attached to them.

Comment: Answered here I believe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57132595/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-when-identity-insert-is-set-to/61210255#61210255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your config by adding below, after `HasKey` method.

`modelBuilder.Entity<Order>() .Property(c => c.Id) .ValueGeneratedNever();`

Answer (score -1):

If you are not going to use "Fluent" (for those who don't want to). When you set your model up you can decorate the field/property as a primary key. Just don't include

> DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

This should set the field in the table as a primary key, but not with autoinc.

[SQL ID column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adlvz.png)

[Identity Colum (auto inc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KRjZ.png)

Comment: I'm not going to downvote.  But this is a downvote candidate because the original question explicitly asks for "Fluent" style.  Not Attribute Style.